# Sublime - File Extension - Settings (.sh Unix Line Endings)

Tags: sublimetext2, settings, sh, sublimetext, line-endings

Is there a way to force Sublime to use a setting ONLY for a given file extension. In my specific case, I'd like to use Unix line endings on the .sh file extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, but the settings are by syntax, not file extension. First, open a `.sh` file, and the syntax should automatically be set to `Shell Script (Bash)`. Next, click on **`Preferences -> Settings-More -> Syntax Specific-User`** and something like the following should appear:

```js
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "bash",
        "zsh",
        "sh",
        "profile"
    ]
}
```

Change it to the following:

```js
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "bash",
        "zsh",
        "sh",
        "profile"
    ],
    "default_line_ending": "unix"
}
```

and save. You can follow this same general principle for any syntax, using any setting available in **`Preferences -> Settings-Default`**.

Comment: Ah, that works! Thanks a lot man. To follow up on that, is there a setting for Unix EOF... or would this work as expected?

Comment: @SC_Chupacabra it should work as expected. I transfer files between Windows, OS X, and Linux all the time, and I've never had an issue.